# timestamp on filename Unix

Tags: macos, unix, datetime, mysql

I am trying to backup `mysql` database with `mysqldump`.

```
    /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump
 --opt  --user=user--password=pass Database> 
 /Applications/MAMP/backup/data.sql
```

I would like the filename to have the current date/time (upto second is okay) in the filename. My data.sql should be `data<current date/time>.sql`. (or from epoch is okay too).

I know I can get current time by using  `date +%s` but how do I use it as a filename. 
I'm using MacOSx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash`, you could just dump to

```
mysqldump Database > data$(date +%s).sql
```

Comment: Thanks.. And what do I do in case I want the date/time. Not from epoch

Comment: @Ankur You mean `+%F%T`? See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) for the formatting rules.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to add the following to my .zshrc file:

```
alias now='date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H%MZ'
```

This gives you a very easy way to make an ISO 8601 formatted Zulu time. Then I would do this:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump --opt  --user=user--password=pass Database> /Applications/MAMP/backup/data-`now`.sql
```